# Update user profileimage in firebase Android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app where a user is registered and can have a profile image. In the realtime database I have these information saved. Now I want to be able to change the informatiom, particulary profile image. Here is my realtime database:

[image]

When the user clicks on his/hers image the camera intent starts:

```
 private void startCamera() {
        //start the camera
        Intent cInt = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cInt,REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                //picture as image
                Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                mProfileRoundedImageView.setImageBitmap(bp);
                
                //here I want to save Image uri and update my firebase with the new uri...
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I do that?? I have searched alot how to convert captured image to uri and then update imageurl but with no luck. Please help.

BTW I do **not** want to save the image to the sd, just convert to uri and update firebase...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below function.

```
  public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        Bitmap OutImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(inImage, 1000, 1000,true);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), OutImage, "Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }
```

Just call it in the onActivityResult() after you extract bitmap

**Feel free to ask if something is unclear**

Comment: Can you please explain the code as I am trying to understand what I code :)

Comment: First check that either it's working or not for you.

Comment: When I try to update my profile it does not look like it is updated. I get the uri as : `content://media/external/images/media/24` which i am not really sure it should look like this. Should't it look like an url?

Comment: If you are getting the correct URI then what's the problem, you just need to upload this to your database. Do you need the code to upload this to firebase storage and get a link?

Comment: I have tried to upload it like this:  `mImageUri = getImageUri(getContext(),bp); HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("imageurl", mImageUri);
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(fUser.getUid()).updateChildren(map);` but it does not work. Do you know how to do?

Comment: Then What's the result?

Comment: Nither my image in my profile changes now for some reason (before it could change) and my imageurl in my database is not updating. do u know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You need to update the url , because when you upload a new image then you get a new   url as a result and you need to update your data in database.. which is updating the image url.... otherwise it will show the old image.. because you have the link of the old image in your database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233342/discussion-between-mohammed-and-kamal-nayan).